# Error no such file or directory, open NodeJs Pkg

Tags: node.js

I try fix this bug of hour i use devtools Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt but no fix this bug
Error

Error! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\nutza\AppData\Local\Temp\pkg.336d76f485351706a5cb69ef\node\out\Release\node.exe'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js isn't installed correctly. Do it again.

Comment: i try do again  first this error send